# How to have the functionality of two parent classes without inheriting from both parent classes

Tags: c++, class, oop, inheritance, unreal-engine5

In my case, there is a base class called Actor in the project. The official documentation provides a plugin with a MouduarActor class that inherits from Actor. Additionally, I am using a third-party library that also has a plugin with a GenActor class that inherits from Actor.

```cpp
class Actor:public Base , public ISomething...
{
    ...
    virtual void PreComponent();
    virtual void PostComponent();
};

class ModularActor:public Actor
{
    ...
    virtual void PreComponent() override 
    { 
        Actor::PreComponent(); 
        ... 

    };
    virtual void PostComponent() override 
    { 
        ...
        Actor::PostComponent();
    };
};

class GenActor:public Actor , public ISomething2...
{
    ...
    void Func1();
    void Func2();
    void Func3();

};

// Here is the method I wanted to do but was prohibited by the project.
class MyActor :virtual public ModularActor , virtual public GenActor
{};
```

Now, I want my Actor to have the functionality of both MouduarActor and GenActor, but the project does not allow me to use multiple inheritance. How can I accomplish this task without resorting to the worst-case scenario of using the copy method?

```cpp
class MyActor :public Actor..(or whatever, but can only be one base class.)
{
    // We have PreComponent and PostComponent inherited from MudularActor.
    // I don't need to override them; 
    // In fact, they should be MudularActor::PreComponent and MudularActor::PostComponent.
    virtual void PreComponent() override;
    virtual void PostComponent() override;

    // Also, I can have the functionality of GenActor.
    void Func1();
    void Func2();
    void Func3();

    // And the functionality of Actor.
    ...
};
```

Comment: Is there some reason you can't make your `ModularActor` inherit `GenActor` instead?

Comment: If you don't need to inherit them, just have them as member variables.

Comment: Just using inheritance for "code reuse" isn't a good idea to have in the first place. So use composition. MyActor can have PreComponent as a normal member function which will call another method on another class that is a member of PreComponent.

Comment: You should probably file a bug to both libraries for failing to inherit from `Actor` virtually. *"project does not allow me to use multiple inheritance"* What do you mean?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Unreal Engine does not allow multi inheritance for their reflected types like Actor.